# Composting in Madison, WI : Sun or Shade

Tags: compost

I have been researching(googling) weather to keep my Earthmachines composting bin in the sun or shade. I've read that keeping in the sun hastens the process, but tends to dry out the mix.

I live in Madison Wisconsin, so we get a few months hot weather in the summers, and the winters are cold. Any advice as to where the composter would be more effective/easier to work with. I can keep the bin on the north side of the house(shade) or the south side of the house(sunny).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure it really matters that much. All else equal, I'd probably keep it in the shade: it's probably going to freeze in the winter no matter where you put it, and the summer sun will bake the moisture out of it.

Though if one side of the house is more convenient, then just put it there. If it gets too dry in the sun, you could always add a little water.